# Lambdas. Memory leak, Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, memory-leaks, xamarin.android

As a novice mobile app developer, I now know that special attention should be paid to the issue of performance, and in particular, memory leaks.

After reviewing something about it here, and then there, an old code came to mind. In the xamarin documentation, in the "Custom button" section, they expose the following example in which they use a lambda expression and that I have used very frequently since I started developing...

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);

button.Click += (o, e) => {
  Toast.MakeText (this, "Beep Boop", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
};
```

Does this cause a memory leak afterwards in native Android code?

It's just to be sure, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seam `this` is an activity. So no it should n't have memory leak issue. Because activity and button had references to each other but there is no reference to something with bigger scope(for example Application). So if system wants to collect the activity it can be done without leaking issue.